# How to get value along with cell number in openpyxl?

Tags: python, openpyxl

Below is the code to read the value of a cell. But I want to print a dictionary with key as cell number and value as the value of the cell. like - {A1,value}.
please help me out

```
from openpyxl import Workbook,load_workbook 
    
    wb = load_workbook('dds.xlsx')
    ws = wb.active
    
    cell_range_c = ws["c"]
    
    
    print(cell_range_c[0].value)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
ret = {x.coordinate: x.value for x in ws["c"]}
```